# Eth address created from an outdated version of MEW off line

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

Hello I have MEW off line client 3.7 (2018 version) on an airgapped computer

Since the new client doesn't let me create new ethereum wallets offline (it blocks itself (idle) while creating it) can I create a new eth wallet from the 2018 MEW off line client? It's the only one that doesn't block itself while creating a new wallet

Once created, then can I saftley send coin to this address? (ethereum address created from the 2018 version of Myethereumwallet offline client)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the private key corresponding to an address, you can safely send funds to that address.

Maybe give MyCrypto's desktop app a try to generate a private key fully offline. You can download it from here: https://download.mycrypto.com. You can copy the installer to your offline computer, and run it from there. There are full instructions for running it offline [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/offline/how-to-run-mycrypto-offline-and-locally), and for sending offline transactions [here](https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/sending/how-to-make-an-offline-transaction).